# how to redirect one link to another link using .htacces file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have to redirect link using .htaccess file. I tried many times but it didn't work.

My link is
[www.example.com/book_details.jsp?resourceID=35570](http://www.example.com/book_details.jsp?resourceID=35570)

I have to redirect to
[www.example.com/abc/book_details?resourceID=35570](http://www.example.com/abc/book_details?resourceID=35570)

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
RewriteRule    ^book_details\.jsp$  

/abc/book_details       [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^book_details\.jsp\?resourceID=([0-9]*)$   

/abc/book_details?resourceID=$1     [NC,L]
```

How to do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `RewriteRule` does not match against the query string. The good news is that you don't need to modify the query string in any way, so you can safely ignore it. So your solution will end up looking like this:

```
RewriteRule ^book_details\.jsp$ /abc/book_details [NC,L]
```

Comment: how to write more than one redirects in htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book_details\.jsp$ /abc/book_details [NC,L]
```

You can test that it works at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, and a good information source is http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html

If not, please check whether URL rewriting is allowed on your webserver.

Comment: How to write more than one redirects in htaccess

Comment: just add a new line, e.g. 
RewriteRule ^book_content\.jsp$ /def/book_content [NC,L]